# Callback Handling

Tags: javascript, node.js

Could someone please confirm if these two methods are effectively the same

```
process.nextTick(callback.bind(undefined, results));
```

Vs.

```
process.nextTick(function() {
   callback(results));
});
```

And if they successfully make the callbacks asynchronous from a node js perspective.

Comment: check out the performance of the two methods: http://jsperf.com/closure-vs-bind-9000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They might be the same, yes.

There's one minor difference though: The time at which `results` is evaluated. When you use `bind`, it takes the value immediately, when you use the callback the value is determined at the time of the actual call.

Example where they're different:

```
var results = 1;
process.nextTick(console.log.bind(console, results));
process.nextTick(function() { console.log(results)); });
results = 2;

// will log "1" and "2"
```

Comment: That's actually quite interesting, I wasn't aware.